# UIProgressView is getting hidden when scrolling the uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I am trying to download a list of urls using asinetworkqueue. It downloads fine. But my uiprogressview is getting hidden when I scroll the uitableview.

I mean if the progress is shown in row no 2, and if I scroll it then the progress view is hidden. Then after completing the download of row no 2 then it displays the progress-view in row no 3.

In short, when scrolling the uitableview, the active uiprogressview is getting hidden.

### Updated

Here are some more clarifications. When a downloading is not completed for a row (for example row no 1), now if I scroll the tableview and see the row no 1, the progressview gets hidden even it is not yet completed the download. once the download completed for row no 1, it starts downaloding for the row no2 and now the progressview is displayed.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"]];

        CGRect tblViewFrame = CGRectMake(7 , 0 , self.view.bounds.size.width - 14, self.view.bounds.size.height - 90);
        self.tblViewDownload = [[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tblViewFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]autorelease];
        self.tblViewDownload.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.tblViewDownload.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
        self.tblViewDownload.scrollEnabled = YES;
        self.tblViewDownload.delegate = self;
        self.tblViewDownload.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.tblViewDownload];

        index = 0;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            [self loadArray];
        }); // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [self.myUrlArray count];
    }


    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
        CGFloat rowHeight = 75.0;

        return rowHeight;  
    }

    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UILabel *lblTitle, *lblAuthor;


        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            lblTitle = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 220, 25)]autorelease];
            lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            //lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
            lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Bold" size:15.0];
            lblTitle.text = @"Sample title";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];

            lblAuthor = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 30, 220, 25)]autorelease];
            lblAuthor.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lblAuthor.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
            lblAuthor.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            lblAuthor.text = @"sample authior";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblAuthor];



        }

        return cell;
    }


    -(void)loadArray{

      NSString *urk = @"http://sample/iphone/video/video_2.mov";
      self.myUrlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

      for( int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        [self.myUrlArray addObject:urk];
      }


      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        [self downLoadPoems];
      });

    }

    -(void)downLoadPoems{

        if( index < [myUrlArray count] )
        {
            NSLog(@"this is the index %d",index);

        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];

        UITableViewCell *Cell = [self.tblViewDownload cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

        progress = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
        progress.frame = CGRectMake(65, 55, 210, 25);
        progress.progress = 0.0;
        progress.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [Cell.contentView addSubview:progress];
        }


        if(!self.networkQueue)
            self.networkQueue = [[[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init] autorelease];

        [self.networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
        [self.networkQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueCompleted:)];
        [self.networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
        [self.networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progress];

        [self.networkQueue setDelegate:self];

        if( index < [myUrlArray count] )
        {        
            NSString *url = [myUrlArray objectAtIndex:index];

            NSArray *aPoemArrayUrls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:url,nil];

            for(NSString* urlString in aPoemArrayUrls)
            {
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
                ASIHTTPRequest *downloadAFileRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url]retain];
                NSString *Filename = [urlString lastPathComponent];
                NSLog(@"%@ filename",Filename);
                [downloadAFileRequest setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request1" forKey:@"name"]];
                [downloadAFileRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:Filename]];
                [downloadAFileRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
                [downloadAFileRequest setDelegate:self];
                [downloadAFileRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
                [downloadAFileRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
                [downloadAFileRequest setShowAccurateProgress:YES];

                [self.networkQueue addOperation:downloadAFileRequest];
                //----
            }

            [self.networkQueue go];


        }





    }

    -(void)queueCompleted:(ASINetworkQueue*)queue{

        NSLog(@"queueCompleted");

       self.tblViewDownload.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UIProgressView *progressv = (UIProgressView*)queue.downloadProgressDelegate;

        if (progressv)
            [progressv removeFromSuperview];


        if ( index < [myUrlArray count] ){

            index++;

            [self downLoadPoems];
        }

    }


    - (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {
        NSLog(@"request done");
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
    }

    - (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {
        NSLog(@"request went wrong");

        NSError *error = [request error];
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
```

Comment: You need to clarify the question - I (and most likely others) do not understand the problem. You have a table with something in row 0. Row 1 has a progress bar, and says "Progress for download xxx" until that completes, then it switches to showing the progress of the next item. You have other items in your table, but they are not related to the first two items. When the user scrolls the table to see some other item, the progress bar is hidden. You want to progress bar to magically stay visible, even though its a cell in the table, and you let users scroll the table. Can you see my confusion?

Comment: @DavidH: First of all thank you for taking time to respond.what is my problem is when a row no 1 is started downloading, the progressview is shown.This is fine.what the problem is when i scroll the uitableview while downaloding is not yet completed for row no 1,now when i again see the row no 1 it is not visible even it is not completed the download.i see no progressview in tht row.after completing the downalod for row no 1, it will display the progress view for row no 2.this is the issue , pls help

Answer (score 1):

Everytime the tableView asks you for a cell you are creating a new one above - its is not correct you shoulc recycle cells (and there are oodles of examples on here and elsewhere in Apple docs on how to do this.)

Now, updating a progress bar in a cell has some complexities you are not dealing with. First, the progressBar is object will change as the table scrolls - it will change out from underneath you. Lets say you have one section to make the steps easier (but these would work with multiple sections too):

So you should only update it by doing the following:

- your downloads wants to update progress. It must determine the table row that has that progress bar (if you add a progress bar to a cell, setting a tag on that view makes it easier to locate it later)
- the code above then asks the UITableView for the list of visible cells, and determines if the cell it needs to update is visible - if not then it does nothing.
- assuming the cell is visible, it asks the cell for its progressBar (ie [cell.contentView viewWithTag:...]), then updates the current value (this progess bar might have been previously showing some other file due to recycling).

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath: you try to recycle a cell, if that fails you create a new cell. After that code you can make no assumptions about ANY of the views - you need to update the progressBar max, set the current value to the current value of the download, change any label text etc.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations:

1. You're setting `setDownloadProgressDelegate` in `ASINetworkQueue`, but if you want to keep track of progress of the individual downloads, you might want to do it in `ASIHTTPRequest`, instead. That way you theoretically can get multiple downloads updating accordingly.
2. One of the reasons I say that is that you're currently creating the `networkQueue` adding a single `ASIHTTPRequest` and kicking it off. You could theoretically queue up a whole bunch of `ASIHTTPRequest` and kick them off, each updating their own `UIProgressView`.
3. The big problem is your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

   - First, you shouldn't really being using unique cell identifiers for each. You lose any and all memory optimization;
   - You should be checking to see if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returned `nil` (not an issue if you use storyboards with prototype cells, but I'm assuming you're not doing that here), and if did, then create the table view and any controls you need;
   - You should, though, be setting the labels and updating the progress bar, regardless of whether `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returned `nil` or not; and
   - Personally, with progress bars, I find it easier to just remove the progress bar if it's already there, and then add it again, regardless of whether `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` was successful or not.
4. You probably want to keep track of an array of "row" objects, which have, for example, the URL of what's being downloaded, but more importantly, a retained `UIProgressView` object (because, annoyingly, the `downloadProgressDelegate` is an `assign` property and won't be retained for you. So, you'll want to keep track of the progress bars for all of the requests currently in progress (whether than cell is visible or not, dequeued or not), not just a single one UIProgressView.
5. By the way, it looks like you're dispatching stuff to a background queue. You don't really need to do that because `ASINetworkQueue` does all of that sort of stuff for you. There might be a technical reason why you might want to do so, but I don't think it's necessary as I think this stuff works asynchronously already. If you really want to kick it off in another queue, that's fine, but just remember to dispatch your UI updates back to the main queue, as you never should be doing UI updates from the background.

FYI, in the code sample below, I use a code pattern that I frequently use for tableviews, notably that my tableview has a model that consists of a NSArray of `Row` objects, which keep track of what I need to for each cell of the tableview.

```
@interface Row : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIProgressView *progress;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *urlString;

@end
```

And I'll use it like follows:

```
@interface SampleViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rows;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue;

@end

@implementation SampleViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.rows = [self loadImageUrls];

    [self downloadStuff];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.rows count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 75.0;
}

#define kTitleTag 1
#define kAuthorTag 2
#define kProgressViewTag 3

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"asi";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *lblTitle, *lblAuthor;

    // if you could use storyboards, a lot of this silliness goes away

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // but in the world of nibs, you have to create the custom controls when you create the cell

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 220, 25)];
        lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
        //lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Bold" size:15.0];
        lblTitle.tag  = kTitleTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];

        lblAuthor = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 30, 220, 25)];
        lblAuthor.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblAuthor.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
        lblAuthor.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        lblAuthor.tag = kAuthorTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblAuthor];
    }
    else
    {
        // if you're recycling a cell, then link up with it's controls

        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        lblTitle = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kTitleTag];
        lblAuthor = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kAuthorTag];

        UIProgressView *oldProgressView = (UIProgressView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kProgressViewTag];
        if (oldProgressView && [oldProgressView isKindOfClass:[UIProgressView class]])
        {
            [oldProgressView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    Row *row = [self.rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    lblTitle.text = row.title;
    lblAuthor.text = row.author;

    if (row.progress)
    {
        row.progress.frame = CGRectMake(0, 55, 200, 25);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:row.progress];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)downloadStuff
{    
    ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];

    [networkQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueCompleted:)];
    [networkQueue setDelegate:self];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ASIHTTP"]
           withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                            attributes:nil
                                 error:nil];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.rows count]; i++)
    {
        Row *row = [self.rows objectAtIndex:i];

        row.progress = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
        row.progress.tag = kProgressViewTag;

        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
        if (cell)
        {
            // if the cell is visible, add the progress view to it

            row.progress.frame = CGRectMake(0, 55, 200, 25);
            [cell.contentView addSubview:row.progress];
        }

        NSString *urlString = row.urlString;

        ASIHTTPRequest *request;
        request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        NSString *filename = [urlString lastPathComponent];
        [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request1" forKey:@"name"]];
        [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ASIHTTP"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] stringByAppendingFormat:@"%1d", i]];
        [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
        [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:row.progress];
        [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];

        [networkQueue addOperation:request];
    }

    [networkQueue go];
}

-(void)queueCompleted:(ASINetworkQueue*)queue
{    
    NSLog(@"%s queueCompleted", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"%s request done: %@", __FUNCTION__, [request responseString]);

    [request.downloadProgressDelegate removeFromSuperview];

    // find which row it's on and remove it from that one

    for (Row *row in self.rows)
    {
        if (row.progress == request.downloadProgressDelegate)
            row.progress = nil;
    }

    // and let it go (obviously, non-ARC, release)

    request.downloadProgressDelegate = nil;
}

- (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"%s request went wrong err = %@", __FUNCTION__, [request error]);
}

- (NSArray *)loadImageUrls
{
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Row *row = [[Row alloc] init];
        row.urlString = @"http://host/test/bigfile";
        row.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title %1d", i];
        row.author = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author %1d", i];

        [results addObject:row];
    }

    return results;
}
```

Clearly, you'll have to customize this for your own purposes (e.g. I tweaked for my own purposes; life's too short for me to waste time writing non-ARC code; etc.), but it shows you how I personally addressed what I saw as the key deficiencies of the code sample you provided. I think this needs considerable extension (gracefully cancel `ASINetworkQueue` if we leave, perhaps only loading `ASIHTTPRequests` for visible cells, etc.), but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]autorelease];

    UILabel *lblTitle, *lblAuthor;





        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        lblTitle = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 220, 25)]autorelease];
        lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        //lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
        lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Bold" size:15.0];
        lblTitle.text = @"Sample title";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];

        lblAuthor = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 30, 220, 25)]autorelease];
        lblAuthor.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblAuthor.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
        lblAuthor.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        lblAuthor.text = @"sample authior";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblAuthor];





    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you used  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; which was inserting a old row in tableview , when you are scrolling down. This method will create new row at every index